# how to migrate changes from pending changelist in master branch to another branch in perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

Let us suppose I have a master branch X and I want to migrate changes to separate branch Y in perforce.

```
changelist #NUMbER in X branch and want to unshelve into Y branch.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a branch spec XY that maps between branches X and Y:

```
Branch: XY
View:
    //depot/X/... //depot/Y/...
```

you can shelve the pending change from X and unshelve it as a pending change on Y:

```
p4 shelve -c NUMBER
p4 unshelve -s NUMBER -b XY
```

If the branches are streams where X is the parent of Y, the syntax is more like:

```
p4 unshelve -s NUMBER -S Y
```